# Adding a regular expression to .vimrc with nmap and imap

Tags: regex, vim

I have a rather hairy vim regular expression that will capitalise words separated with underscores as below

```
my_text_example -> My_Text_Example
```

The regular expression is

```
s/\(\<\|_\)\([a-zA-Z]\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)/\u\1\u\2\L\3/g
```

I would like to map that to a key sequence (for example gc). I would also like it to work in visual selection mode.

I tried this

```
nmap gc :s/\(\<\|_\)\([a-zA-Z]\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)/\u\1\u\2\L\3/g<CR>
```

in my .vimrc, but I get an error that the regular expression is not found. I haven't tried the imap version, hopefully that will be simple once I get an answer for the nmap case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
nmap gc :s/\(\<\\|_\)\([a-zA-Z]\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)/\u\1\u\2\L\3/g<CR>
```

I think it didn't work because \< is a zero-width pattern but that is just a wild guess.

If someone can explain why it didn't work that'd be great!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much. The imap version was just the same, didn't need to change anything.